# How can I have multiple ASP.NET Core APIs running on a single website?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-8, kestrel-http-server

My website is hosted at a provider running IIS.

Instead of creating a single, ubiquitous web application, I'd like to create multiple, separate micro services and store them in different folders of my website, like this:

```
- Static Content (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)
|-- ASP.NET Core application #1
|-- ASP.NET Core application #2
|-- ASP.NET Core application #3
```

How can I do this?

### EDIT

The question to me is: What do I need to configure in IIS to have `/folder1/*` requests be handled by webApi1 (i.e. Kestrel), `/folder2/*` requests be handled by webApi2 (Kestrel again) and `/*` requests by IIS itself. — And what path would I need to provide to `app.MapGet("")`, `app.MapPost("")` etc.

Comment: I would avoid using microservices until your domain exhibits the requirements that outweigh the complexity of implementing such an architecture. That said, you would typically have an API gateway sitting in front of your services which would be responsible for directing incoming requests and communication between services handled by a message bus/broker.

Comment: IIS does not have the concept of "folders" unfortunately. You need to study the IIS terms and then deploy those applications under the same site, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Comment: Instead of posting new information in comments, always edit your question please.

Comment: @LexLi: So, can you come up with an answer? Or just with comments?

Comment: This is impossible. If you want to host multiple ASP.NET Core applications in a single iis website, there will definitely be errors. My suggestion is to use [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7).

Comment: Thank you, @samwu, for your valuable reply. Would you want to convert your comment into an answer? I would happily want to upvote.

Comment: @AxD I've converted the comment into an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. If you want to host multiple ASP.NET Core applications in a single iis website, there will definitely be errors.

My suggestion is to use [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Answer (score -1):

Microservices is the concept of separating the project into different folders
If you want to make the APIs in more folders just add another API project

Comment: The question to me is: What do I need to configure in IIS to have `/folder1/*` requests be handled by `webApi1` (i.e. Kestrel), `/folder2/*` requests be handled by `webApi2` (Kestrel again) and `/*` requests by IIS itself. — And what path would I need to provide to `app.MapGet("")`, `app.MapPost("")` etc.